# Xcode /Parse Not Getting Test User Data [Parse Starter Kit 1.9.0 + 1.9.1]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

New to coding apps, not new to programming languages. Followed directions for Parse/Xcode and Parse has yet to receive any data from any of my successful builds.

Can someone help me out here? I have started over 10 projects, did research for the last 10 days, and can not find any information about this problem.

Specific issue:

I start a new app via Parse, then create a matching XCODE project/target/workspace.

I enter the correct API keys, and enter the test code that Parse gives in my viewDidLoad() function.

I compile, I run, its successful, and according to Parse, the user data should've been send to them.

But when I look in Parse, there is no user data.

Any word on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to refresh the entire dashboard, not just hit their refresh button. Click the project name in the top left corner and reselect your project.